# WPF show video in ellipse shape

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement, clipping

I want to show a video in an ellipse shape.

How can I do it?

Can I use the Clip property on it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<MediaElement Source="YourMediaElement">
    <MediaElement.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="150,150" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
    </MediaElement.Clip>
</MediaElement>
```